# How do I do select in list with Ebean createSqlQuery

Tags: mysql, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm building a Play2 app with Ebean. I have created a service class with a method for getting venues by a list of ids:

```
public static List<Venue> getVenuesForIds(List<Long> list){          
    ArrayList<Venue> venues = new ArrayList<Venue>();
    String sql = "select c.id, c.name from Company c where in (:ids)";
    List<SqlRow> sqlRows =
                Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).setParameter("ids", list).findList();        
    for(SqlRow row : sqlRows) {
        venues.add(new Venue(row.getLong("id"), row.getString("name")));
    }        
    return venues;
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
[PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in (201639091,201637666)' at line 1 Query was: select c.id, c.name from Company c where in (?,?) ]
```

I have read through http://www.avaje.org/ebean/introquery.html but probably missed the correct syntax. I want to do this in raw sql.
What have I missed?

Comment: Just curious: `Venue` is a model which table's name is `Company` or you are selecting with it objects of other model?

Comment: Hello! I'm accessing the database from a new app where venue is more appropriate name for the entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request does not seem correct.

What about :

```
 "select c.id, c.name from Company c where c.id in (:ids)";
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to perform such 'sophisticated' query, it will be good enough if you'll use common `Finder<I,T>` in your `Venue` model (once):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Company")
public class Venue extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;
    public String name;
    // other fields

    public static Finder<Long, Venue> find
            = new Finder<Long, Venue>(Long.class, Venue.class);
}
```

So then you can do the same task with... single line of code in your method:

```
 public static List<Venue> getVenuesForIds(List<Long> ids){          
     return Venue.find.select("id,name").where().idIn(ids).findList();
 }
```

or with similar expresion:

```
 public static List<Venue> getVenuesForIds(List<Long> ids){          
     return Venue.find.select("id,name").where().in("id",ids).findList();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you and your are of course correct! But in this case I want to use raw sql since I will perform joins later on and I do not want to create the entities for that in my code.